# TabView (SwiftUI): Respond onTab on an already active tabItem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ContentView.swift which contains a TabView.

View1 has a NavigationView in it with some childViews.
View2 is just a single View.

I would like to perform some action (always return to View1, even when being in a childView of View1), when the first tabItem is pressed. **Even if it is already the active tabItem.**

I tried onTapGesture as seen below, which didn't seem to do anything. Adding it right before ".tag(0)" didn't change anything, either:

```
TabView {
    View1()
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Test")
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext")
                .font(.system(size: 25))
            Text("View1")
        }.tag(0)

    View2()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                .font(.system(size: 25))
            Text("View2")
        }.tag(1)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct TestTabSelectionAction: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        let selection = Binding<Int>(
            get: { self.selectedTab },
            set: { self.selectedTab = $0
                print("Pressed tab: \($0)")
                if $0 == 0 {
                           // <<< your action here !!
                }
        })

        return TabView(selection: selection) {
            View1()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "doc.plaintext")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                Text("View1")
            }.tag(0)

            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                    Text("View2")
            }.tag(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The typical need to do this for TabItems (or SegmentControls) is to scroll to the top of the tab content, and this answer isn't really a good solution for that. All you know is the index of the tab pressed, you don't have access to the tab itself. Seeing how you closed other questions as duplicates when they were asking for this specifically, maybe you should write a more extensive answer (or stop using the modhammer for dupes to your own answer)

Comment: This solution fully solves the issue described in the question. Maybe it doesn't solve other requirements, but for those you can ask new questions.